# Would EVA foam under the carpet (for sound proofing) be a fire risk?

Tags: subfloor, sound-proofing, building-regulations, fire-hazard

I'd like to put some EVA foam under the carpet (above the floorboards) on the first floor bedroom of my house, to dampen the sound of foot steps. The [fire safety building regulations](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/485420/BR_PDF_AD_B1_2013.pdf) (section B2) say that the provisions do not apply to upper layers of floors since they don't play a major part in the spread of fires. Does that mean it is ok to use or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Be aware that installing unapproved padding under carpet will often void the warranty. Too much movement will lead to tearing over time. Too little results in early compression damage.

Comment: Carpet pad is already foam, and there are premium choices.  Do you expect the EVA foam to be that much better?

Comment: @JPhi1618 I don't expect that it will be any better than carpet foam, but I have already bought lots of EVA foam and now wondering if I can use it.